# Firebase could not upload my nextjs project to f hosting due to a big mount of files (423.19 MB)

Tags: next.js, firebase-hosting

Firebase could not upload my nextjs project to f hosting due to a big mount of files (423.19 MB)
I have dynamic route [pid].js page with approximatly 900 x (3 languages) ; so 2700 pages + my other pages
I need to deploy those dynamic pages for SEO perpose.
I now that there is Incremental Static Regeneration but i need to deploy old posts
But i beleive there is to option to resolve that:

- reduce .Directory (to upload) folder size by using firebase ignore
- introducing ISR to do that
  but how?

I tried a variety of solutions:
1- try to reduce generated dynamic pages [pid].js using condition like so:

```
export async function getStaticPaths({locales}) {
  const postsRef = ref(database, references.POST_FILTER_REFERENCE);
  const postsQuery = query(postsRef);
  const querySnapshot = await get(postsQuery);
  //const pots = await ads.snapshot;
  console.log("locales", "-->"+locales);
  var posts = Object.values(querySnapshot.val());
  var paths;
 

  var paths =posts.map(post => (post.postId > 500 && {params: {pid: post.postId}})).flat();
    
 
  console.log(`locales______________> ${JSON.stringify(paths)}`);
  return {
    paths: paths,
    fallback: false,
  }
}
```

I have approximatly 950 x 3 paths as you see:

```
[{"params":{"pid":"8"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"8"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"8"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"27"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"27"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"27"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"31"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"31"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"31"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"32"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"32"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"32"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"33"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"33"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"33"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"37"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"37"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"37"},"locale":"en"}...,{"params":{"pid":"634"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"635"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"635"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"635"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"636"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"636"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"636"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"637"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"637"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"637"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"638"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"638"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"638"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"639"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"639"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"639"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"640"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"640"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"640"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"641"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"641"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"641"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"642"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"642"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"642"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"643"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"643"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"643"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"644"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"644"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"644"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"645"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"645"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"645"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"646"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"646"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"646"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"647"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"647"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"647"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"647"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"647"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"647"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"649"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"649"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"649"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"650"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"650"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"650"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"651"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"651"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"651"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"652"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"652"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"652"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"653"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"653"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"653"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"654"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"654"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"654"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"655"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"655"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"655"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"656"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"656"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"656"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"657"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"657"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"657"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"658"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"658"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"658"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"659"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"659"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"659"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"660"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"660"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"660"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"661"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"661"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"661"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"662"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"662"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"662"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"663"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"663"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"663"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"664"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"664"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"664"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"665"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"665"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"665"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"666"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"666"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"666"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"667"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"667"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"667"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"668"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"668"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"668"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"669"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"669"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"669"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"670"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"670"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"670"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"671"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"671"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"671"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"672"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"672"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"672"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"673"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"673"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"673"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"674"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"674"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"674"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"675"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"675"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"675"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"676"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"676"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"676"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"677"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"677"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"677"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"678"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"678"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"678"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"679"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"679"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"679"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"680"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"680"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"680"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"681"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"681"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"681"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"682"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"682"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"682"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"683"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"683"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"683"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"683"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"683"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"683"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"691"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"691"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"691"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"692"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"692"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"692"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"693"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"693"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"693"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"694"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"694"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"694"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"696"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"696"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"696"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"697"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"697"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"697"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"698"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"698"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"698"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"699"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"699"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"699"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"700"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"700"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"700"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"701"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"701"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"701"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"702"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"702"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"702"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"703"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"703"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"703"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"704"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"704"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"704"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"705"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"705"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"705"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"706"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"706"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"706"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"707"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"707"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"707"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"708"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"708"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"708"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"709"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"709"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"709"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"710"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"710"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"710"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"711"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"711"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"711"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"713"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"713"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"713"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"714"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"714"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"714"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"715"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"715"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"715"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"716"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"716"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"716"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"717"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"717"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"717"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"718"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"718"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"718"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"719"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"719"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"719"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"720"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"720"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"720"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"721"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"721"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"721"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"722"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"722"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"722"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"723"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"723"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"723"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"724"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"724"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"724"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"725"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"725"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"725"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"726"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"726"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"726"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"727"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"727"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"727"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"728"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"728"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"728"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"734"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"734"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"734"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"736"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"736"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"736"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"738"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"738"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"738"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"739"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"739"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"739"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"740"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"740"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"740"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"741"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"741"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"741"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"742"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"742"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"742"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"743"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"743"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"743"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"744"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"744"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"744"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"744"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"744"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"744"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"746"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"746"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"746"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"748"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"748"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"748"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"749"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"749"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"749"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"750"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"750"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"750"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"751"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"751"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"751"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"752"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"752"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"752"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"753"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"753"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"753"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"754"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"754"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"754"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"755"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"755"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"755"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"756"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"756"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"756"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"757"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"757"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"757"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"758"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"758"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"758"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"759"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"759"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"759"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"760"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"760"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"760"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"761"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"761"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"761"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"762"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"762"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"762"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"763"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"763"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"763"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"764"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"764"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"764"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"765"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"765"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"765"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"766"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"766"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"766"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"767"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"767"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"767"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"768"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"768"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"768"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"769"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"769"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"769"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"770"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"770"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"770"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"771"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"771"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"771"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"772"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"772"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"772"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"773"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"773"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"773"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"774"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"774"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"774"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"775"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"775"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"775"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"776"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"776"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"776"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"777"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"777"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"777"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"778"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"778"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"778"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"779"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"779"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"779"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"780"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"780"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"780"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"781"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"781"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"781"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"782"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"782"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"782"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"783"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"783"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"783"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"784"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"784"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"784"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"785"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"785"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"785"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"787"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"787"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"787"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"788"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"788"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"788"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"790"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"790"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"790"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"791"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"791"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"791"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"792"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"792"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"792"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"794"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"794"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"794"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"795"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"795"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"795"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"796"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"796"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"796"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"797"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"797"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"797"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"798"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"798"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"798"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"799"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"799"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"799"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"800"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"800"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"800"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"801"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"801"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"801"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"802"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"802"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"802"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"803"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"803"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"803"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"804"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"804"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"804"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"805"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"805"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"805"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"807"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"807"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"807"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"808"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"808"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"808"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"809"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"809"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"809"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"810"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"810"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"810"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"811"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"811"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"811"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"812"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"812"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"812"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"813"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"813"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"813"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"814"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"814"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"814"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"815"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"815"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"815"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"816"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"816"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"816"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"817"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"817"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"817"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"818"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"818"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"818"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"819"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"819"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"819"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"820"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"820"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"820"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"821"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"821"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"821"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"822"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"822"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"822"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"823"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"823"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"823"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"824"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"824"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"824"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"825"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"825"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"825"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"826"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"826"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"826"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"827"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"827"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"827"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"828"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"828"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"828"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"829"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"829"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"829"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"830"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"830"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"830"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"831"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"831"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"831"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"832"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"832"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"832"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"833"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"833"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"833"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"834"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"834"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"834"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"835"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"835"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"835"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"836"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"836"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"836"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"837"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"837"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"837"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"838"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"838"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"838"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"839"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"839"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"839"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"841"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"841"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"841"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"842"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"842"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"842"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"843"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"843"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"843"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"844"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"844"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"844"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"845"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"845"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"845"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"846"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"846"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"846"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"847"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"847"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"847"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"848"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"848"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"848"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"849"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"849"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"849"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"850"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"850"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"850"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"851"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"851"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"851"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"852"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"852"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"852"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"853"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"853"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"853"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"854"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"854"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"854"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"855"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"855"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"855"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"856"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"856"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"856"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"857"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"857"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"857"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"858"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"858"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"858"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"859"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"859"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"859"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"860"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"860"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"860"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"862"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"862"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"862"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"863"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"863"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"863"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"865"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"865"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"865"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"866"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"866"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"866"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"867"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"867"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"867"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"868"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"868"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"868"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"869"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"869"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"869"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"870"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"870"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"870"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"871"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"871"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"871"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"872"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"872"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"872"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"873"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"873"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"873"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"874"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"874"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"874"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"875"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"875"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"875"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"876"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"876"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"876"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"877"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"877"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"877"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"878"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"878"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"878"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"879"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"879"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"879"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"880"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"880"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"880"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"881"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"881"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"881"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"882"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"882"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"882"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"883"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"883"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"883"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"884"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"884"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"884"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"886"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"886"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"886"},"locale":"en"}...,{"params":{"pid":"958"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"958"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"958"},"locale":"en"},{"params":{"pid":"959"},"locale":"fr"},{"params":{"pid":"959"},"locale":"ar"},{"params":{"pid":"959"},"locale":"en"}]
```

and is log debug from firebase:

[image]

Comment: just one edit: here is how i generate my dynamic page paths:  var paths =posts.filter(post => (post.postId > 500 )).map(post =>  {params: {pid: post.postId}}